# How can I show column "State Category" of a Work Item in a Query?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I need to build a query on a Board and show a column containing the "State Category" of the Work Item.

I'm using the DevOps interface to build my query (I'm not writing any code).

Unfortunately when I go to select the columns to be displayed, the "State Category" is not there and I can only select "State" column.

How can I show the "State Category" column in my query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I show column “State Category” of a Work Item in a Query?

For this issue, I am afraid this is currently impossible to achieve. The column that can be added in Query needs to be a field. In the process of Organization Settings we can see that there is no field named "State Category".

[image]

[State categories](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/states-customization-on-team-services/#state-categories) are a named grouping for a set of states that allow experiences such as the backlog and board to work with customized states. The product currently supports five state categories: `Proposed`, `In Progress`, `Resolved`, `Completed`, `Removed`.

Currently you can add State Category column in Analytics views. Here is a [case](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7271) you can refer to.

[image]

Comment: @Paolone67 Currently, it is not possible to create a query based on Analytics view in Azure Devops. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.